# Converting desired local angular velocity to global angular velocity

Tags: math, 3d, rotation

I'm working on adding camera controls to a program that doesn't have them through memory-editing, but can only change global angular velocity on each axis. How would I go about taking a desired local angular velocity, for example pitching the camera up at a rate of 1 radian per second, and getting the global angular velocities that equal it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a local-to-global matrix of your camera somehow.

Then you may create a quaternion from your local axes, convert it to global by multiplying it with the matrix and convert it back to Euler representation.